# SUM hours.minutes as total correct hours.minutes

Tags: mysql, time, sum

I'm looking for a string (mysql) that could sum couple of hours.minutes for total timecorrectly. I cannot find anything right.

Example:

```
id|  time_spent|
1 |  10.15     |
2 |  10.15     |
3 |  10.15     |
4 |  10.15     |
5 |  10.15     |
```

I Can sum this by:

```
Select sum(time_spent) as total_hours from table
```

but the result is: 50:75 but should be like **51:15**

I've tried also this:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( SEC_TO_TIME( `time_spent` ) ) ) 
AS total_time FROM table
```

but the result is: **00:00:50**

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(SECOND(time_spent))) AS total_time FROM 
table
```

but the result is: **00:00:50.750000**

Is there any possible to get a total correct hours.minutes from these above records?

Comment: What type is `time_spent`?

Comment: Just a typo, I guess. `SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( SEC_TO_TIME( `time_spent` ) ) )` should be `SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time_spent` ) ) )`.

Comment: time_spent is a varchar.

Comment: SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( time_spent ) ) ) FROM table = 00:00:50.750000

Comment: Your difficulty is due to you storing a time data type as a string. Fix that and your problem will solve itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, t TIME NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table (t) VALUES 
('10:15:00'),
('10:15:00'),
('10:15:00'),
('10:15:00'),
('10:15:00');

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(t))) x FROM my_table;
+----------+
| x        |
+----------+
| 51:15:00 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would also be use an appropiate data type (like `time`). But if you are stuck with this idea of having an varchar, you could convert your time in seconds, summing it up and convert back.

`TIME_TO_SEC` would expect the format HH:MM, but you have some fancy floating point there, so your best shot would be parsing:

```
TIME_TO_SEC(SUM(STR_TO_DATE(time_spent,'%H.%i')));
```